# whats the purpose of installing maven on MAC

Tags: maven

when I search for installing maven, I found videos on how to instal maven on eclipse and how to instal maven on MAc.It may be very basic question but just wondering whats the purpose of installing maven on MAC? I use maven on eclipse already

Comment: No clue what you're asking. Be more specific. If the information you've found doesn't apply to you, then ignore it. *I searched Google for information about cooking food, but they talk about beef and I only eat vegetables. What should I do?* - Don't read the posts that reference beef.

Comment: Well,I was trying to understand  that probably If I install maven on my mac then if I am executing code through terminal it will be helpful otherwise if I am running the code through eclipse then having maven on eclipse will work.Hope I have added some clarity to my question

Comment: You've added no clarity to your question, because you've not made it more clear what you're asking, and you've not made an [edit] to your post to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You would install Maven to be able to execute  the `mvn` command from the command line (usually Terminal.app).  This is usually because you need to do things that your IDE does not easily allow you to do, or to ensure that your project builds correctly with plain Maven.

This is important because the Maven emulation in Eclipse is good but not perfect (as there are some design decisions in Eclipse that do not work well with the Maven mindset).  A typical situation is that Eclipse does not treat `src/test` different from `src/main` and Maven does.  The easiest way to ensure this, is to build your projects from the command line once in a while.

Comment: A final test is alway to check your build on plain command line (iTerm2 etc. ) on Mac.

Comment: Thanks Thorbjorn & khmarbaise .